# With apollo-server how to get child field info argument in parent

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server and I was wondering if there was a way to get info (the fourth argument of a resolver) as it would be received by one specific child field but in the parent resolver of said child field.

My use case is as follows: i have a mutation called edit_x that as two fields 'before' and 'after'. I need to resolve the 'before' field before (meh) i make the mutation, so i need to resolve it in the parent. I use a library called joinmonster to resolve my graphql requests that hit the db and this library require the info of a field to resolve, but what i need is not the info of 'edit_x' but the info of 'before'.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What information from the child field's `info` object are you trying to gleam?

Comment: @DanielRearden i'm looking to the code of joinmonster right now to determine exactly that thanks for the idea of splitting up what the library needs from the info object instead of trying to generate whole info object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GraphQLResolveInfo` object that's passed to the resolver is built for each field being resolved and that doesn't happen until the resolver for the field is about to be called. Check out the source [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/329f35718d1e8683995f682f0805250aec37ce9d/src/execution/execute.js#L650). The parent field is resolved before the child fields, so there's technically no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: ok if i want child info it's not possible directly, if i really need it i should handle myself  the parts of the info object that are used by joinmonster to resolve the child fields and create a fake info object to give to it thanks